# Why does dual-casting reanimate corpse turn zombie directly into ash

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Steps to reproduce:

1. Get Dual-casting conjuration perk
2. Dual-Cast reanimate on a normal
   dead enemy (one that would work normally if not dual-cast).
3. The body turns to ash.

This happens every time I dual cast this spell. Is there something I'm missing? I was hoping it would increase the duration or power level of the zombie.

I have conjuration around 45, which I know isn't very high...

The questions are - why does this happen? Is this works-as-designed? And are there any circumstances where I *can* dual-cast a reanimate spell for good results?

edit: I know I can dual-cast summon familiar/flame atronach. I think that increases the duration, which is okay. But I prefer zombies! (and have picked some perks to do with undead)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are dual-wielding (in the sense that you "charge" one of your hands, then "charge" the other hand, then deploy them both) then what's happening is: Your first spell is striking the corpse and begins to re-animate it while your second spell hits the zombie. Since you can only re-animate a corpse once, when the second spell hits the zombie it causes it to disintegrate (like it does when the time expires or the zombie is killed). If that is what is wrong, then you must "charge" both of your hands at the same time so that a single energy ball is created.

Comment: Wow thanks! I never thought of that. I'll try that tonight and accept answer if that was the problem.

Comment: @John So did that work?

Comment: Thanks - it works, you activate both hands at the same time, and a cool animation plays with the magic between both hands. Then the spell works normally. I didn't time it but I'm going to assume it increases the duration. So full of win - Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone else has difficulty timing the dual cast - if you try to double cast but you didn't get them at the same time (i.e. the cool animation with the magic between both hands doesn't play), simply sheath and try again.